# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0

Tags: android, gradle

When I use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+` in my project's `build.gradle`(module) it works without any error. But when I just use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28`, just without `.+`, it gives me an error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0

Just without the `.+` end of it. I added maven before but the result was the same. Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> `28.0.0` is the final version of support libraries. Android has migrated to AndroidX. To use the latest android libraries, [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

---

> *Edit:* Versions `28.0.0-rc02` and `28.0.0` are now available.

I don't see any `28.0` version on [Google Maven](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html). Only `28.0.0-alpha1` and `28.0.0-alpha3`. Just change it to either of those or how it was previously, i.e., with `.+` which just means any version under `28` major release.

For an alpha appcompat release `28.+` makes more sense.

Comment: everything was fine once I update android studio I started facing same error today. Any update?

Comment: I've set `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and I still get `Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.` error

Comment: make sure `google()` is added in `repositories` in `android/build.gradle`

Answer (score 34):

Add the following code on build.gragle (project) for adding Google maven repository

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) clearly states that you should you this if your gradle version is under 4.1

Answer (score 20):

some guys who still might have the problem like me (FOR IRANIAN and all the coutries who have sanctions) , this is error can be fixed with proxy
i used this free proxy for android studio 3.2
https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod
just to to `Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)` and search `HTTP proxy` then check `Manual proxy configuration` then add `fodev.org`
for `host name` and `8118` for `Port number`

[image: Screenshot of proxy settings in android studio]

Answer (score 13):

As @Sourabh already pointed out, you can check in the [Google Maven](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) link what are the packages that Google has listed out.

If you, like me, are prompted with a similar message to this `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0`, it could be that you got there after upgrading the `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion`.

What is basically happening is that the package is not being found, as the message correctly says. If you upgraded the SDK, check the Google Maven, to check what are the available versions of the package for the new SDK version that you want to upgrade to.

I had these dependencies (on version 27):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

And I had to change the SDK version and the rest of the package number:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Now the packages are found and downloaded. Since the only available package for the 28 version of the SDK is `28.0.0` at the moment of writing this.

Comment: For me it seemed that I need to only add 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' then 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' would stop complaining.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
gradlew -q app:dependencies
```

It will remove what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

my problem was just network connection. using VPN solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`

All to add

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your buildToolsVersion version tallies with your app compact version.

In order to find both installed compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion go to Tools > SDK Manager. This will pull up a window that will allow you to manage your compileSdkVersion and your buildToolsVersion.

To see the exact version breakdowns ensure you have the Show Package Details checkbox checked.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" (HERE)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.truecitizenquiz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' (HERE)
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in build.gradle , the version of bellow line should be same

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```