# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

I am studying *react-native* and when running `react-native run-android` throws an error:

`Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.`

The following are the things I did so far but still getting the same error,

1. Changed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` version manually from `PROJECT_NAME/android/app/build.gradle`. See photo https://ibb.co/vVPjcgw.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Downgrade *react-native* version from 0.58.4 to 0.57

Please check my react-native info for details. https://ibb.co/4W38PSc

Still no good. What are your suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450521/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v728-0 Have you seen this?

Comment: Open the Android Studio em try to rebuild the project. Probably the Gradle will update your dependencies. If this does not effect, put the output error message here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo problem most probebly

try,

**implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"**

instead of

**implementation "com.android.support:appcompatv7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}**